# use requirements.txt generated in windows for environment in Unix

Tags: python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

My development environment is running in Windows 10 and I have created a virtualenv:

```
> virtualenv venv
> .\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

Now I do some package installations, for example `pandas` or `numpy`. Everything is fine until here. Then I have to install also `ipykernel`, which seems to install also `pywin32`. Which is also listed in the `requirements.txt` when it is genrated.

I am using GitLab's CI/CD pipeline and I have used one of the [configuration templates](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Python.gitlab-ci.yml) as a guide. My customized configuration:

```
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python -V  # Print out python version for debugging
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt


stages:
    - Test

unit-test:
    stage: Test
    image: python:3.9.1
    script:
        - python -m unittest -v
```

But the pipeline fails with
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==300 (from versions: none)`

**What I already understand is:** that `pywin32` is specific for Windows OSs and therefore will not be installed in Unix OSs, i.e. the `requirements.txt` will not work.

**What I would like to know:**

Is it possible to generate a list of the requirements, that would also be usable for sharing with Unix users? Also, I wonder if the process that I am trying to apply is best practice / if it makes sense. I have not yet made any experiences with `setup.py`. Would that be the better option in this case?

Do I need a specific `requirements-win.txt` & `requirements-unix.txt` to setup development environments across a team for example?

**What I would like to achieve:**

Run a pipeline after pushing to the repository. The Pipeline is pulling a Docker, hence it is an Unix environment. The showstopper for now is the Windows specific package in the `requirements.txt` that cannot be installed in that said virtualenv inside the container.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/#examples

Comment: This somehow explains to me what I could manually add in the `requirements.txt`. And basically this seems to be a good hint, thanks for that! @phd But I am still not very sure if doing it like that is a good practice, because it requires manual steps. I now ended up with adding just the names of packages (without version numbers) to the `requirements.txt` and then create run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in my working directory / the virtualenv. Doing this I can be sure the container will collect what it needs and also that my machine collects the necessary on its site...